# FileSystem listStatus throwing NullPointerException

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I am trying to list the contents of a directory present inside the HDFS. I tried out the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String uri = args[1];
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri),conf);

    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Args: " + args[i]);
    }

    Path[] paths = new Path[args.length];
    for(int i=1; i<args.length;i++){
        paths[i] = new Path(args[i]);
        System.out.println(paths[i]);
    }

    FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(paths);
    Path[] listedPaths = FileUtil.stat2Paths(status);
    for(Path p : listedPaths){
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

But I am getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.fixRelativePart(FileSystem.java:2198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1539)
    at com.demo.ListStatusDemo.main(ListStatusDemo.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Please let me know on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here in your code:

```
for(int i=1; i<args.length;i++){
    paths[i] = new Path(args[i]);
....
```

since you for loop is 1-based, you left paths[0] == null  (that is unassigned)

Comment: I changed the index to `paths[i-1] = new Path(args[i]);` but still getting the same exception. Please advice.

Comment: @user182944 if you do `paths[i-1]` then the path at `paths[paths.length-1]` will be null, thus the exception.

Comment: Yep, just do {Path[] paths = new Path[args.length-1];}